# How can I make my DIV element wider? Why does my code fail?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/antonpug/jfrNt/

I am trying to make all the buttons the same size, and I am setting width to 100, but it doesn't do anything. Ahh! So frustrated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[modified a bit,](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrNt/16/)

- you need to use percentage and set it in the `<li>`
- make the `<a>`'s `display:block` to fill in the whole `<li>`
- added `box-sizing:border-box` (CSS3) to include the border in width calculation
- replaced `display:inline` with `float:left`. elements styled with `display:inline` CANNOT have dimensions (width and height) and top and bottom padding and margins will not move it away from the text baseline (not move it vertically). Elements floated left seem to automatically have `display:block`
- changed IDs to classes since IDs can only appear once

Comment: You did not fix the issue of multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: thanks! I didn't notice that. it all seemed to work even when ID was used.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting width:150px on the #menu_item declaration which is targeting the id of menu_item. For one, you can't have more than one element in a page with an id="menu_item" attribute.

What you need to do is set the  tag inside those divs to display:block as it is by default an in-line element, then you can specify a width on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use the same ID multiple times.
2. You can't set a width or margin on **inline** elements.

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrNt/11/) with the following changes:

- Changed to `.menu_item` class.
- `.menu_item` is now `display: inline-block`.
- `.menu_item a` is now `display: block`.

I'm not sure if the margin on the top is supposed to be there, but you can remove that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you want fixed widths,  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrNt/12/)

had change your divs to use class not id,

.menuitem is now display: block and float: left;

.menu has a min-width to prevent wrapping of the menu items.